# How can I get groupshapes in word and save as?

Tags: c#, ms-word

How can I get groupshapes in word and save as?
now I get Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.GroupShapes,What should I do next?

```
        object Nothing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object filename = "D:admin.docx";
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application WordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(ref filename, ref Nothing, ref Nothing, ref Nothing, ref Nothing, ref Nothing, ref Nothing, ref Nothing, ref Nothing, ref Nothing, ref Nothing, ref Nothing, ref Nothing, ref Nothing, ref Nothing, ref Nothing);
        WordApp.Visible = true;
        int i = 1;
          foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.GroupShapes shape in WordDoc.Shapes)
          {
          }
        WordDoc.Close(ref Nothing, ref Nothing, ref Nothing);
        WordApp.Quit(ref Nothing, ref Nothing, ref Nothing);
```

Comment: how can i doooooooooooooooooo!